# How to create Split Image Effect with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

Please refer this http://54.66.151.166/

=> Go to Canvas->Split Image->Select Size and Shape.

=> Refer various sizes given and proceed for next step.

=> Upload any image and check for the canvas effect for various sizes.

If I to develop the same kind of functionality with the using only jquery or canvas, does any have idea how can I implement this?

Comment: please read How to ask before... http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then create question with single real problem

Comment: hi areim, can you tell me where is the confusion, i think this is clear and also this single real problem as well... :)

Comment: e.g:
Search, and research and keep track of what you find.
Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself.
Your question is too global, it sound like "hey guys, I'm too lazy doing it myself, can anybody create this for me?"

Comment: "does any have idea how can I implement this?", this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

we are going to make an image splitting effect

**HTML**

```
        <!--START THE IMAGE PARTS HOLDER-->  
        <div class='images_holder'>  

            <!--INSERT THE SAME IMAGE IN 2 DIVS, THEY BOTH HAVE image_div CLASS AND left OR right CLASS DEPENDING ON POSITION-->  
            <div class='image_div left'><img class='box_image' src='img.jpg' style='width:300px'/></div>  
            <div class='image_div right'><img class='box_image' src='img.jpg' style='width:300px'/></div>  

            <!-- WE USED CSS FLOAT PROPERY, SO WE NEED TO CLEAR NOW-->  
            <div class='clear'></div>  

        </div>  
        <!--END THE IMAGE PARTS HOLDER-->  

        <!--START THE TEXT-->  
        Just some dummy text.  
        <!--END THE TEXT-->  

</div>  
<!--END THE MAIN CONTAINER-->
```

**CSS**

```
.box_container{  
position:relative; /* important */  
width:300px; /* we must set a specific width of the container, so it doesn't strech when the image starts moving */  
height:220px; /* important */  
overflow:hidden; /* hide the content that goes out of the div */  
/*just styling bellow*/  
background: black;  
color:white;  
}  
.images_holder{  
position:absolute; /* this is important, so the div is positioned on top of the text */  
}  
.image_div {  
    position:relative; /* important so we can work with the left or right indent */  
    overflow:hidden; /* hide the content outside the div (this is how we will hide the part of the image) */  
    width:50%; /* make it 50% of the whole images_holder */  
    float:left; /* make then inline */  
}  
.rightright img{  
    margin-left: -100%; /* 100% is in this case 50% of the image, so this is how we show the second part of the image */  
}  
.clear{  
    clear:both;  
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

        //when the user hovers over the div that contains our html...  
        $('.box_container').hover(function(){  
            //... we get the width of the div and split it by 2  ...  
            var width = $(this).outerWidth() / 2;  
            /*... and using that width we move the left "part" of the image to left and right "part" 
            to right by changing it's indent from left side or right side... '*/  
            $(this).find('.left').animate({ right : width },{queue:false,duration:300});  
            $(this).find('.right').animate({ left : width },{queue:false,duration:300});  
        }, function(){  
            //... and when he hovers out we get the images back to their's starting position using the same function... '  
            $(this).find('.left').animate({ right : 0 },{queue:false,duration:300});  
            $(this).find('.right').animate({ left : 0 },{queue:false,duration:300});  
            //... close it and that's it  
        });  

});
```

Comment: Hey GS, thanks for your reply,but this is not the thing what you have given here. It seems you have put two images into two div and on hover jquery effect will take place. But what I want is Single image will be split in multiple tiles.